# Can't login to tty

Tags: login, tty

I was trying to upgrade my 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS. While upgrading, the system suddenly showed a screen saying you system is running in low graphic mode.
Now to solve this I wanted to go through the steps listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).

Now to follow these steps I need to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login. The problem is I can't seem to login. It says login incorrect everytime. I have tried resetting the password but no luck. And I also checked if it is a keyboard layout issue and if `/home` is encrypted. It is neither.

Comment: Did you try typing out the password once at the TTY (as the username, just to see what is displayed) and once when logged in (use the dash or something) just to see if this isn't a keyboard layout issue?

Comment: Yes I did. Not a keyboard layout issue.